# how to prevent an SQL Injection Attack?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection, sql-server-2012

Currently, I am creating an SQL Query by doing something like

```
string SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
foreach(word in allTheseWords)
{
     SQLQuery = SQLQuery + " column1 = '" + word + "' AND";
}
```

I understand that this can lead to an SQL Injection attack. I don't know how to pass an array as a parameter

```
where report in @allTheseWords
```

===========

I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: What SQL database system are you using? E.g. SQL Server, Oracle, etc.

Comment: solution: Use Entity Framework.

Comment: A good start would be to read up on [parameterised queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

Comment: Not quite sure if it's the same way in C# but here is one: http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC5F8BFE541D972472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182310%28VS.100%29.aspx) is the recommendation from Microsoft:

1. Use Code Analysis to detect areas in your Visual Studio projects that are prone to sql injection;
2. Refer to the article on how to reduce risk of attack:

On short they talk about:

- using a stored procedure.
- using a parameterized command string.
- validating the user input for both type and content before you build the command string.

Btw, you can enable static analysis as part of your build process and configure it so that when a security rule is broken, the build also breaks. Great way to make sure your team writes secure code!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass an array as a parameter without adding a user-defined type for table-valued parameters. The simplest way around this restriction is to create individually named parameters for each element of the array in a loop, and then bind the values to each of these elements:

```
string SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 in (";
for(int i = 0 ; i != words.Count ; i++) {
    if (i != 0) SQLQuery += ",";
    SQLQuery += "@word"+i;
}
...
for(int i = 0 ; i != words.Count ; i++) {
    command.Parameters.Add("@word"+i, DbType.String).Value = words[i];
}
```

You can also create a temporary table, insert individual words in it, and then do a query that inner-joins with the temp table of words.

Answer (score 2):

Using ADO you can do it with the help of params

```
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(conString);
SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand();
string SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
int i=1;
foreach(word in words)
{
      Com.Parameters.Add("@word"+i.ToString(),SqlDbType.Text).Value = word;
      SQLQuery = SQLQuery + " column1 = '@word"+i.ToString()+"' AND ";
      i++;
}
Com.CommandText =SQLQuery;
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, you'd use a [Table-Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). SQL has one structure that represents a collection of multiple items of the same type. It's called a table. It doesn't have arrays.

---

Of course, your supposed updated query:

```
where report in @allTheseWords
```

Isn't equivalent to your original query, but may be closer to the intent. In the query constructed using `AND`, you're saying that the *same* column, in the *same* row has to be equal to multiple different words. Unless all of the words are equal, this will never return any rows. The updated query answers whether *any* of the words match, rather than *all*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use prepared statements. The way those are handled is that you write your query and put placeholders for the values you want to use. Here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = @word
```

You then have to go through a prepare phase where the SQL engine knows it will need to bind parameters to the query. You can then execute the query. The SQL engine should know when and how to interpret the parameters you bind to your query.

Here's some code to do that:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, rConn);

// Create and prepare an SQL statement.
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = @word";
command.Parameters.Add ("@word", word);
command.Prepare();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: does this go inside the existing loop that I have?

Answer (score 0):

```
I combine the use of params with HtmlEncoding(to get rid of special characters where not needed). Give that a shot.

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{     
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @id";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.paramaters.AddWithValue("@id", System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(id));
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

        }
    }
}
```